# Python 3: CSV Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am working with a simple csv file and want to know how to update the values contained in a specific cell on each row using data my script has generated.

```
column1, column2, colum3, column4,
bob, 20, blue, hammer
jane, 30, red, pencil
chris, 40, green, ruler
```

Then:

```
new_colour = [pink, yellow, black]
```

Is there a way to take the list <new_colour> and write each list item into the values under colum3 within the csv file? To have it end up like below:

```
column1, column2, colum3, column4,
bob, 20, pink, hammer
jane, 30, yellow, pencil
chris, 40, black, ruler
```

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: 'test_domain_application_data.csv' has the data you want to update? You want to read the existing CSV, update the data, then write. What are the rules for what you want to overwrite? make this a small working example and we'll have a better chance at answering.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my Q to attempt to be more clear.

Comment: You'll need to load the CSV into your Python script, and write out a new, modified one. If it is very large, do it *"on-the-fly"* i.e. reading, modifying and writing as you go. If it is small, and it's simpler, read the whole CSV, modify and then write in one go. You can delete or rename the existing CSV as `XXX.csv.bkup` before writing the new file. If there are other processes simultaneously accessing the CSV while you change it, save the new file as `XXX.csv.inprogress` till it is completely written then rename it when complete so everyone gets a consistent view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (probably unoptimized) solution could be using the pandas module, as long as your CSV file is not too big:

```
PATH_TO_CSV = <your_path>
new_colour = ['pink', 'yellow', 'black']

df = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV)
df['colum3'] = pd.Series(new_colour)
df.to_csv(PATH_TO_CSV)
```